# How do I add 3G connectivity?

Tags: hardware, android

How do I extend the hardware of Raspberry Pi to add GSM/3G connection? Is it likely that the Android port will be able to utilise such a connection?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This site is really for questions about a specific problem you may be having. Yours is perhaps a bit too broad and may promote extended; discussion. I would suggest that you have a Google for existing solutions yourself: and come back if you have any issues. For example, [this site](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2012/07/3g-internet-on-raspberry-pi-success/) offers a good 3G solution.

Comment: No problem. That was on the first results page when searching for Raspberry Pi 3G.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw this tutorial and seems you do not need an Arduino for attaching the 3G.

http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-3g-gprs-gsm-gps

Answer (score 1):

There are 3G dongles. You can pop one into your Rpi or you can attach and Arduino with a GSM/3G shield.

Normally you can find a lot of Linux compatible ones on sites like dealextreme. Do mind you need to have a look at the driver (this might need compiling).

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi.SE. Would you recommend any particular 3G dongle? Once inserted, how do you connect to the internet? What software needs installing? Any warnings for using such a dongle?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain wouldn't that be against policy of suggesting a particular piece of peripherial device?

Comment: Not if you have a working example - examples is always better of course. What software etc is quite important though.

Answer (score 0):

This video was posted weeks after the question was asked. Not sure about 3G though
http://priyank.in/2012/09/myphone-5-a-gsm-based-phone-using-raspberry-pi-and-simcom-900/